# Drools 7.0: All accumulate functions must be registered before building a resource

Tags: drools

We have a running project using Drools 6.5 and want to migrate it to 7.0.

When changing version of Drools dependencies and running the project, the following exception is thrown:

```
All accumulate functions must be registered before building a resourceUnknown accumulate function: 'countDistinct' on rule 'IPCPF001'. All accumulate functions must be registered before building a resource. : [Accumulate: input=[AND [[Pattern: id=null; objectType=MyFact]] ]]
```

We use accumulate functions and they are properly registered in META-INF/drools.packagebuilder.conf file. Anything changes to 7.0 version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After debugging Drools 7.1 initialization process we found out that the properties naming convention changed.

- Until 6.5: META-INF/drools.packagebuilder.conf
- From 7.0: META-INF/kie.properties.conf

Changing the file name to kie.properties.conf solved the problem.